# Problem With Calling WCF endpoint using AJAX jQuery

Tags: .net, ajax, wcf, jquery, jsonp

i have a WCF 3.5 service where i need to call it using jQuery as cross domain call, when i call the service i have return correct response but jQuery throw an exception parsererror status
 this is the code i use to call the WCF service

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var wordlist = $("#main-container").text()


        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            url: 'http://192.168.1.210:8080/XXXX.SPServices/GlossaryService.svc/GetWordsWithDifenition',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            data: { 'stringwords': wordlist },
            success: function (data) {
                PutLinkToDefinition(data);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                debugger;
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

jQuery calls the error function and throws this error

> jQuery161074459453323911_1309093997517
>   was not called

and this is my WCF service

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Application;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System.Net;
using System.Configuration;

namespace XXXX.SPServices
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]

    public class GlossaryService
    {
        // To use HTTP GET, add [WebGet] attribute. (Default ResponseFormat is WebMessageFormat.Json)
        // To create an operation that returns XML,
        //     add [WebGet(ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Xml)],
        //     and include the following line in the operation body:
        //         WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/xml";
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet]
        public Dictionary<string,string>  GetWordsWithDifenition(string stringwords)
        {
            ......
        }



}
```

this is the markup

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="XXXX.SPServices.GlossaryService" CodeBehind="GlossaryService.svc.cs"  Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebScriptServiceHostFactory" %>
```

your help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF 3.5 doesn't support cross domain calls / JSONP out of the box. You must either upgrade to [WCF 4](http://www.gutgames.com/post/Enabling-JSONP-in-WCF.aspx) or check [this sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716898%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).